# Python Selenium Webdriver add method to Webelements/ custom 'assert' statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I’m trying to add a few `methods` to `WebElements` that I use frequently. I figured out how to make it work, but now my assert statements fail. Here is what I have. How do I get my `assert` to work?

```
def is_below(self, above_element):
    below = self.location['y']
    above = above_element.location['y']

    self.assertLess(above, below)

WebElement.is_below = WebElement_is_below
```

In reality, this is all the logic I am trying to figure out:

```
class ModifiedTestCase(TestCase):
    def is_below(self, above_element):
            below = self.location['y']
            above = above_element.location['y']

        self.assertLess(above, below)

        WebElement.is_below = WebElement_is_below


class SeleniumTest(ModifiedTestCase):

    def test_web_page(self):

        above_element = self.find_element()
        below_element = self.find_element()

        below_element.is_below(above_element)
```

The error I get is “WebElement has no attribute assertIn”. I know I can pass it a `driver` argument, but that defeats some of the simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a solution. I used an `assert` statement.

```
class ModifiedTestCase(TestCase):
    def WebElement_is_below(self, above_element):
        below = self.location['y']
        above = above_element.location['y']

        assert above < below, f'"{below}"  > "{above}"'

    WebElement.is_below = WebElement_is_below


class SeleniumTest(ModifiedTestCase):

    def test_web_page(self):

        above_element = self.find_element()
        below_element = self.find_element()

        below_element.is_below(above_element)
```